# How to reduce icon resource request count in Web page test, can we still use css sprites?

Tags: wordpress

I have too many icons on the website mostly png icons, I am having too many requests in web page test for these icons as background images, how can I increase reduce these requests, maybe css sprites is still a good option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to stack overflow, in my opinion in order to reduce the server request for small png files, if those are used as icons, you can convert them to base64 code and add it as a background image.

Check: https://www.base64-image.de/

Comment: Thanks, checking it out

Comment: it will have any effect on css file? since it will become huge in size? these codes are very long chain of characters

Comment: It will but maybe it will be less as compared to png images, glad to know its working.